# Php Delete item from mysql data base

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpmyadmin

Hope some one can help me out here, i guess am not calling my functions right. 
Am trying to retrieve some data from my database and have a delete link attached to each items being retrieved, so that when ever i click on delete, it will delete that particular item which have the delete function.

My Code to retrieve items from database are as follows.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("uloaku", $con);
$count = 1;
$y = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transaction");
if(mysql_num_rows($y) != 0){

echo "<table bgcolor=\"white\" width=\"1000\" bordercolor=\"grey\" border=\"5\" >";
echo "<tr>
<td align=\"center\">No</td>
<td align=\"center\">Date</td>
<td align=\"center\">Current Balance</td>
<td align=\"center\">Avaliable Balance</td>
<td align=\"center\">Account Status</td>
<td align=\"center\">Delete Account</td>

</tr>";

while ($z = mysql_fetch_array($y, MYSQL_BOTH)){
        echo "<tr>
        <td align=\"center\">".$count++."</td>
        <td align=\"center\">".$z[1]."</td>
        <td align=\"center\">".$z[2]."</td>
        <td align=\"center\">".$z[3]."</td>
        <td align=\"left\" width=\"300\">".$z[4]."</td>
        <td><a href=\"delete.php\">delete</a></td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }
?>
```

And my code to delete

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("uloaku", $con);
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM transaction WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1") or die   (mysql_error());
header("Location: vacct.php");
?>
```

I know am missing out the logic here and hope somebody can direct me or show me the easy way out. at the moment i can successfully retrieve my items from the data base my only problem is to be able to apply the delete function each time the delete button is tapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code.I have added validation and encryption

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("uloaku", $con);
$count = 1;
$y = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transaction");
if(mysql_num_rows($y) != 0){

echo "<table bgcolor=\"white\" width=\"1000\" bordercolor=\"grey\" border=\"5\" >";
echo "<tr>
<td align=\"center\">No</td>
<td align=\"center\">Date</td>
<td align=\"center\">Current Balance</td>
<td align=\"center\">Avaliable Balance</td>
<td align=\"center\">Account Status</td>
<td align=\"center\">Delete Account</td>

</tr>";

while ($z = mysql_fetch_array($y, MYSQL_BOTH)){
        echo "<tr>
        <td align=\"center\">".$count++."</td>
        <td align=\"center\">".$z[1]."</td>
        <td align=\"center\">".$z[2]."</td>
        <td align=\"center\">".$z[3]."</td>
        <td align=\"left\" width=\"300\">".$z[4]."</td>
        <td><a href=\"delete.php?id=".base64_encode($z[0])."\">delete</a></td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }
?>

code to delete

<?php
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("uloaku", $con);
$id = base64_decode($_GET['id']);
if(!empty($id)){
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM transaction WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1") or die   (mysql_error());
}
header("Location: vacct.php");
?>
```

Comment: @shail base64 is _encoding_, not encryption.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the `id` when you click on the delete link:

```
<a href=\"delete.php?id=$z[theIdKey]\">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><a href=\"delete.php\">delete</a></td>
```

How are you passing the id to delete to your delete.php script?

Comment: Am not sure the correct way to pass the id so that it can delete that particular item retrieved from the data base

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<td><a href=\"delete.php\">delete</a></td>
```

to:

```
<td><a href=\"delete.php?id=".$z[0]."\">delete</a></td>
```

if $z[0] is the ID.

In your delete.php, make sure you also escape the word "transaction" using backtick:

```
DELETE FROM `transaction` WHERE id=123
```

this is because "transaction" is a reserved mysql keyword.

Please also read on [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).